HTML тест с вопросами, пожалуйста помогите
сделал тест надо печатать по нему отчет, как напечатать не только fio а и добавить в печать другие переменные: wrong-answers, right-answers
Работает только fio


function printContent(el){ 
      var printZone = document.getElementById(el).innerHTML; 
      var printWindow = window.open('', '', 'left=0,top=0,width=800,height=900,status=0'); 
      printWindow.document.write('<title>Печать содержимого</title>'); 
      printWindow.document.write('<style>@media print { .no-print { display: none; } }</style>'); // Скрываем элементы, которые не предназначены для печати 
      printWindow.document.write(printZone); 
      printWindow.document.close(); 
      printWindow.focus(); 
      printWindow.print(); 
      printWindow.close(); 
   }



function closeDialog() {
  let fio = document.getElementById("name").value;
  document.getElementById('fio').innerHTML = fio;
    document.getElementById("Dialog").close();
    // Закрываем диалог
  }
<dialog class="Dialog" id="Dialog"open>Введите ваше ФИО!
        <button type="button "id="cancel" onclick="closeDialog()">Продолжить</button>
        
        <form>
        <input class="name" type="text" id="name" name="name" >
        </form>
        </dialog>
    
    
    <body onload="NextQuestion(0)">
    <main>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <!-- creating a modal for when quiz ends -->
        <div class="modal-container" id="score-modal">

            <div class="modal-content-container">

                <h1>Поздравляем вы прошли тестирование!</h1>

                <div class="grade-details">
                    <p>Всего вопросов : 20</p>
                    <p>Неправельные ответы : <span id="wrong-answers"></span></p>
                    <p>Правельные ответы : <span id="right-answers"></span></p>
                    <p>Статистика : <span id="grade-percentage"></span>%</p>
                    <p ><span id="remarks"></span></p>
                </div>
                
    
                
                
                
                
                
                <div class="print"> 
   <button onclick="printContent('printableArea')">Печатать раздел</button> 
   <div id="printableArea"><div id="ca"></div>
       <div id="fio"></div> + <span id="right-answers"></span>+<div id="correctAnsvers"></div><span id="correctAnsvers"></span>печать
       :<div id="correctAnsvers"></div>
   </div>
</div>



